# Applying border using pseudo class

Tags: css

I am applying padding-right directly for my image for some reason. And now I wanted to apply the border style but exactly to the image for which I tried box-sizing method too but no help.

```
img{
    padding-right: 1em;
    border: 5px solid red;
}


<img src='path.jpg' />
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ab77g/)

Padding should not be removed but border should be applied exactly to the boundary of image. How can I do that?

---

**Update:**

Is there any idea to make it work like after pseudo class.

```
img:after{
    content: " ";
    border: 5px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

---

Applying margin or adding span before image won't work in my case because the idea is that the image is set to `width: 100%;`. Here is an example demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Ab77g/17/

Comment: try using `margin-right` instead of `padding-right`

Comment: But in my case I've to use padding!

Comment: Padding and margin almost looks same, except for the fact that padding is inside the border and margin is outside the border

Comment: first try to under stand the box-model property of tags what you are asking is impossible if you use padding. Because it increase the size between the border and the content.

Comment: Yes I know the difference between padding and the margin but in my case margin won't work. So is it not possible to do?

Comment: @SajithNair : :D thanks for telling us the fact .. :D

Comment: @Era I couldn't understand what was so funny about my comment, could you please explain?

Comment: @SajithNair She(Era) was unknown about that so thanked you. no funny fact there.

Comment: please have a look in my updated question.

Comment: Still not understanding your strange requirement. If you can write a pseudo class, why cant you write a img class itself which overrides the padding? See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sajith/6W6RT/

Comment: padding value should be there (i.e. the space)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the previous comments that a Margin would be the best way to achieve what you want done, but, for the sake of solving the riddle, with a span, and a class, and an alteration to your layout, you could do it this way, while still using padding instead of margins:
in your html file:

`<span class=foobar><img src="path.jpg" /></span>`

in your css file:

```
 span.foobar{
   padding-right: 1em;

 }
img
{
    border: 5px solid red;
}
```

This answer was made using the demo code from your question.

Answer (score 0):

yes now we can work upon it with `div` (your latest update) **[like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Ab77g/18/)**

```
div{
    width: 200px;
    position:relative;
}
div:after {
    background: #fff;
    border-left: 5px solid #FF0000;
    content: "";
    height: 134px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -46px;
    top: 0;
    width: 41px;
}
```

Comment: do not work in my case so I exactly need to do with image tag.

Comment: but div contains more images and headings too.